# Net::SMTPFatalError 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses

I am getting this error while I am trying to send password reset instructions to an email 
 id.

```
 Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
```

I have no idea how to fix that issue. I have written smtp settings in config/development.eb as follows:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
:port                 => ...,
:domain               => "...",
:user_name            => '...',
:password             => '...',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:content_type         => 'text/html'
```

}

I am asking if anyone has any idea about how to fix that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can only send emails to verified emails using SES if you're in sandbox mode, you have to request production access from AWS to send out to unverified emails, see [Amazon's documentation about it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) for more information

If you want to change out of sandbox mode, go to your [SES Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#dashboard:) and request production access

If you just want to add more verified emails and stay in sandbox mode, go to [Verified Sender's Email](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#verified-senders-email:) and add in the new email addresses.

Hope this helps

Comment: This helped me after hours of trouble-shooting! The regions have to match: the production access and the verification (domain and/or email) and also the email limit increase, if you use that. I hadn't really noticed the different regions.

Answer (score 5):

You can also come across this issue if you are trying to send an email and specify an email that you don't own.

For example if you are working with a 'Contact Us' form where the user fills in their email, it might be tempting to say `from: user@not_our_domain.com` but you should avoid this. Rather set the email headers as something like `from: noreply@domain_we_own.com, reply_to: 'user@not_our_domain.com'`

Answer (score 0):

Another tip that might help, if you are sending from `'alias <example@example.com>'`, make sure to add it to the SES dashboard exactly as it is. Adding `'example@example.com'` only might not work.